# How to properly authenticate into Jenkins webhooks from Github when LDAP is enabled?

Tags: authentication, github, build, jenkins, webhooks

We have done a fair amount of work and have come pretty close to getting Jenkins to automatically kick off a build when a push is made into Github.  However, Github is logging an error from Jenkins when attempting to post to the Github plugin webhook as follows:

*Error 401 Either no such user 'CN=Github Account,OU=Jenkins,OU=Applications,DC=mydomain,DC=com' or incorrect password; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece?]*

We have LDAP enabled in our environment to allow for active directory logins. An account called "github" has been created on our domain and authorized as a Jenkins user.  **We are able to manually login to Jenkins by punching in the username and password for this account and it works as expected.**  The "github" account has been authorized on the project for READ and BUILD directives on the job.

On Github, the push webhook has the url defined as follows:

http://github:password@jenkins.mydomain.com:8080/github-webhook/

We can confirm that the push event effectively triggers the post to the URL, but the response is a 401 with error details as described above.  We know the account is valid and the password is correct, but we are stuck because we cannot understand why Jenkins suggests that it is invalid.

We have used the following link, among many others as a guide:

http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2011/09/20/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github

As far as we can tell, the only difference between our configuration and those of others who have posted about their success on blogs and here on Stackoverflow is our use of LDAP authentication.

Does anyone have any guidance to help us overcome this hurdle?  Currently, we can successfully run a build manually, so our communication TO Github FROM Jenkins is tip top.  But Github back to Jenkins is a frustrating no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now working.  Here is what went wrong.  When configuring the following string, pay careful attention to both the username and password:

http://github:password@jenkins.mydomain.com:8080/github-webhook/

In our case, the password contained special characters that Jenkins was tripping over.  Usernames and passwords with special characters must be URL encoded or the authentication will fail. For example, the following password

!test+pw

must be URL encoded as follows:

%21test%2Bpw

Comment: Providing credentials in the URL should not be considered as a satisfying secured answer. Private URLs are better although not perfect.